# Coin Combinations Through Brute Force

Tags: java, optimization, dynamic-programming

I have some code that will brute force solve the following problem:

> Given a set of x coins and a target sum to reach, what is the fewest number of coins required to reach that target?

The code so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class coinsSum {
    public static int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    public static int[] combination;
    public static final int TARGET = 59;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();

        int[] validCoins = new int[] {1, 2, 5, 10, 20};
        Arrays.sort(validCoins);
        int len = validCoins.length;

        ArrayList<Integer> maxList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int c : validCoins) {
            maxList.add(TARGET / c);
        }

        int[] max = new int[len];
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            max[i] = maxList.get(i).intValue();
        }

        permutations(new int[len], max, validCoins, 0); // bread&butter

        if(min != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The combination " + Arrays.toString(combination) + " uses " + min + " coins to make the target of: " + TARGET);
        } else {
            System.out.println("The target was not reachable using these coins");
        }

        System.out.println("TOOK: " + (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000 + "ms");
    }

    public static void permutations(int[] workspace, int[] choices, int[] coins, int pos) {
        if(pos == workspace.length) {
            int sum = 0, coinCount = 0;
            System.out.println("TRYING " + Arrays.toString(workspace));
            for(int a = 0; a < coins.length; a++) {
                sum += workspace[a] * coins[a];
                coinCount += workspace[a];
            }
            if(sum == TARGET) {
                // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(n)); //valid combinations
                if(coinCount < min) {
                    min = coinCount;
                    combination = workspace;
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(combination)+" uses " + min + " coins");
                }
            }
            return;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <= choices[pos]; i++) {
            workspace[pos] = i;
            permutations(workspace, choices, coins, pos + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This solution uses recursion, is there any way to do compute combinations in java using loops?

How else can all possible combinations be iterated through?

Comment: If the code works and you're only seeking for improvement, then go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: "Any way?" Yes.  Other question is too broad, the code review site mentioned is a good idea.

Comment: I did post a version of this, but it received no responses, so I sought help here
@markspace I will edit the question then t make it less generic

Comment: can you have repetition of coins

Comment: @Amir yes, you can have an infinite amount of any coins, but if you have more than T/C of a coin it will overshoot the target, where T is the target and c is the coin value, eg. T = 5, C = 2, 5/2 = 2 of them is the most possible in a valid solution

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Answer (score 2):

You can sort the array of coins. Then go from right to left, keep subtracting from the target value, untill the coin is bigger from the remaining value of target. Move left in the array of coins and repeat the process.

Example:

```
{1, 2, 5, 10, 20}
num = 59

Try coins from right to left:
59 - 20 = 39
So far coins used [20]

39 - 20 = 19
So far coins used [20,20]

19 - 20 = -1, Can't use 20!
19 - 10 = 9
So far coins used [20,20,10]

9 - 10 = -1, Can't use 10!
9 - 5 = 4
So far coins used [20,20,10,5]

4 - 5 = -1, Can't use 5!
4 - 2 = 2
So far coins used [20,20,10,5,2]

2 - 2 = 0
So far coins used [20,20,10,5,2,2]
Total coin used 6
```

Comment: this works for certain lists of coins (American coins are an example of this) but doesn't for others. For example, if you have the coins {1, 3, 4} and you want to make 6, that algorithm would produce an answer of [4, 1, 1], but optimal being [3,3]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in python that uses dynamic programming to find the minimum number of coins to reach a target value.

The algorithm works as follow

```
dp[i][target] = minimum number of coins required required to acheive target using first i coin
dp[i][target] = min(dp[i-1][target],dp[i-1][target-coin[i]]+1)
dp[i-1][target] denotes not using the ith coin
dp[i-1][target-coin[i]] denotes making use of ith coin
```

Since for each coin your are checking wheather to include it or not the algorithm is enumerating through all possible combination.

Here is an space optimized version of the above algorithm

```
maxvalue = 10 ** 9
def minchange(coins, target):
    no_of_coins = len(coins)
    dp = [maxvalue for i in range(target + 1) ]
    dp[0] = 0
    for i in range(no_of_coins):
        for j in range(coins[i], target + 1):
            dp[j] = min(dp[j], dp[j - coins[i]] + 1)
    return dp[target]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a dynamic programming approach which is definitely not optimised, but isn't too bad for target numbers up to 10000 if anyone is interested

```
import java.util.*;

public class coinSumMinimalistic {
    public static final int TARGET = 12003;
    public static int[] validCoins = {1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.sort(validCoins);

        sack();
    }

    public static void sack() {
        Map<Integer, Integer> coins = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        coins.put(0, 0);
        int a = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= TARGET; i++) {
            if(a < validCoins.length && i == validCoins[a]) {
                coins.put(i, 1);
                a++;
            } else coins.put(i, -1);
        }
        for(int x = 2; x <= TARGET; x++) {
            if(x % 5000 == 0) System.out.println("AT: " + x);
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i <= x / 2; i++) {
                int j = x - i;
                list.add(i);
                list.add(j);
            }
            coins.put(x, min(list, coins));
        }
        System.out.println("It takes " + coins.get(TARGET) + " coins to reach the target of " + TARGET);
    }

    public static int min(ArrayList<Integer> combos, Map<Integer, Integer> coins) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < combos.size() - 1; i += 2) {
            int x = coins.get(combos.get(i));
            int y = coins.get(combos.get(i + 1));
            if(x < 0 || y < 0) continue;
            else {
                total = x + y;
                if(total > 0 && total < min) {
                    min = total;
                }
            }
        }
        int t = (min == Integer.MAX_VALUE || min < 0) ? -1:min;
        return t;
    }

    public static void print(Map<Integer, Integer> map) {
        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("[" + entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue() + "]");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```